# Uses seed.rb on Rails to set has_many Associtation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have class Food and Category like this.

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_foods
  has_many :categories, through: :category_foods
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_foods
  has_many :foods, through: :category_foods
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class CategoryFood < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :category
  validates :food_id, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true
end
```

And in seed.rb file I do this.

```
category_list = [
  "VietNam",
  "Korea",
  "Japan",
  "Europe"
]

food_list = [
  ["rau muong", 10000, "anh rau muong", "rau muong tuoi ngon, dam bao sach se"],
  ["rau ngot", 15000, "anh rau ngot", "rau ngot tuoi ngon, ve sinh an toan thuc pham"],
  ["thit bo", 120000, "anh thit bo", "thit bo sach, co ngon goc ro rang"],
  ["ot", 10000, "anh ot", "ot ngon, khong cay, nguon goc ro rang"]
]

Food.delete_all
CategoryFood.delete_all

food_list.each do |name, price, image, description|
  Food.create(name: name, price: price, image: image, description: description)
end

Category.delete_all

category_list.each do |name|
  Category.create(name: name)
end
```

So how i can create CategoryFood in seed.rb?

Comment: How do you decide which `Food` must be paired with which `Category`?

Comment: Decide random :). How can i do

Comment: Do you know how you would do it anywhere else in your code? You can do it in the same way in seed.rb

Comment: @alexanderbird i do this in seed.rb :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find_by` to fetch the record for a specific `name` for both `Food` and `Category` models, and get their `id` values; for example:

```
CategoryFood.create(
  food_id: Food.find_by(name: "rau muong").id,
  category_id: Category.find_by(name: "VietNam").id
)
```

Just repeat that code for each `Food`/`Category` pair you need to create in `CategoryFood` model.

For random seeding you could use something along this lines:

```
random = rand(Category.count)

Food.all.each do |food|
  CategoryFood.create(food_id: food.id,Category.offset(random).first
end
```

I wont't recommend doing `rand` on both ids since it could create duplicates.

Comment: I see. But when i use this, terminal displays that:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @HãnhNguyễn Are all `Food` records being created? You must create first all foods (and categories) before creating `CategoryFood` records. So, if you are testing in console, firs create all food records.

Comment: i know. But can I use rails db:seed to make all databse without rails in console?

Comment: Yes, to seed the db just run `rails db:seed` in terminal. Does doing that still outputs an error?

Comment: I think that when i uses this, Food will be borned first, next is Category. And last is CategoryFood. But when run, the terminal display that don't have Category with id = "2". I used your code :)

Comment: opps. I do this. Thank you very much :))) @Gerry

Comment: @HãnhNguyễn Great! Don't forget to accept answer (by clicking the tick on the left).

Comment: @HãnhNguyễn Welcome to SO!